# After adding AWS ACM EKS ELB is not opening on HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio, knative

I have my app running on EKS which is using istio-ingressgateway service for load balancer and Knative serving I have added ACM to my ELB, but after patching the service with

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:xx-xxxx-1:1234567890:certificate/xxxxxx-xxx-dddd-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
```

my domain is not opening on HTTPS but works fine on HTTP giving this error on HTTPS

```
< HTTP/1.1 408 REQUEST_TIMEOUT
HTTP/1.1 408 REQUEST_TIMEOUT
< Content-Length:0
Content-Length:0
< Connection: Close
Connection: Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you your load balancer forward the traffic from 443 to the backend target port 3190 in case of Istio. Check your Istio gateway file wether you have 443 port mapped with the targets.